# Disqus Universal Code is not working with new disqus_identifier

Tags: javascript, disqus

This code displays the comments when the thread disqus_identifier is pointing to returns comments, but when it's a thread with zero comments, I get an error message that reads "We were unable to load Disqus. If you are a moderator please see our troubleshooting guide."

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
var disqus_shortname = 'my_short_name'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname
var disqus_identifier = 'random';
/* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
(function() {
    var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
    dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
})();
</script>
```

There has to be some way to create an empty thread.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: When it says "We were unable to load Disqus", it gives you a link where everything is explained. Please read the documentation before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Look like your site is inaccessible, you can use Disqus JavaScript configuration variables

```
var disqus_developer = 1; // developer mode is on
```

This tells the Disqus service that you are testing the system on an inaccessible website, e.g. secured staging server or a local environment

http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472098-javascript-configuration-variables

Also verify your `disqus_shortname` variable

Comment: This is no longer correct, the variable has been deprecated. http://iainbarnett.me.uk/articles/disqus-developer-mode